# In sphinx search, how do I match by a filled string?

Tags: database, string, full-text-search, sphinx

Hopefully this is a simple one.

I am trying to do a search for all records where the firstname is john and the lastname is not an empty string (''). In regular SQL, this would look like...

```
select id, firstname, lastname from users where firstname = 'john' and lastname != '';
```

With sphinx's extended query syntax, from what I understand in their [documentation](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/latest/extended-syntax.html), it should look like this.

```
select id, firstname, lastname from users where match('@firstname john @lastname !\'\'');
```

However, with the above query, I still get blank last names.

```
+---------+------------------+----------+
| id      | firstname        | lastname |
+---------+------------------+----------+
|  110809 | John             |          |
|  313681 | John             |          |
|  520045 | John             |          |
|  554136 | John             |          |
```

If I try this query:

```
select id, firstname, lastname from users where match('@firstname john')
```

I get exactly the same results as above, making me believe the lastname clause is not doing a thing.

Has anyone had to do this with sphinxsearch before? Any pointers or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use index_field_lengths = 1 in your index (plan or RT) config. After that you should automaticaly have an attribute `<field_name>_len` you can use to filter out (or find) documents with empty field contents, e.g.

```
mysql> desc table;
+----------+------------+
| Field    | Type       |
+----------+------------+
| id       | bigint     |
| name     | field      |
| a        | string     |
| name_len | tokencount |
+----------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into table values(1,'abc', 'abc');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into table values(2,'', '');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from table where name_len != 0;
+------+------+----------+
| id   | a    | name_len |
+------+------+----------+
|    1 | abc  | 1        |
+------+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

index_field_lengths requires reindexation for a plain index or re-creation for an RT index.

Comment: Thank you, this is more of a match to the problem we've got, and solves a few other issues too.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx (and Manticore for that matter) - indexes words in the documents. So it can't match 'nothing', because there is nothing in the index to match!

As an alternative to using a length attribute, could make 'nothing' *something* to index :)

```
sql_query = SELECT id, firstname, IF(lastname='','_NONE',lastname) as lastname FROM ...
```

Then can match that

```
... where match('@firstname john @lastname -_NONE');
```

or even if going to ALWAYS want to exclude such rows, could just exclude them from index :)

```
sql_query = SELECT ... FROM users WHERE lastname != ''
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!